# error { error: bind message supplies 11 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 12

Tags: rest, prepared-statement, postgresql-9.3

I have created post api but not able to figure out why am I getting this error ? Any suggestion for what I need to change in my query?
Query :

```
   router.post('/bills', function(req, httpres, next) {
    console.log("Inside the bills api");
     const name = req.body.name;const designation = req.body.designation; const department = req.body.department;
    const address = req.body.address;const phone = req.body.phone;const mobile = req.body.mobile;const email = req.body.email;
     const organization = req.body.organization;const city = req.body.city;const state = req.body.state;const pincode = req.body.pincode;const fax = req.body.fax;
 console.log(name,designation,department,address,phone,mobile,email,organization,city,state,pincode,fax)
        pool.query("Insert into bill_to(name,designation,department,address,phone,mobile,email,organization,city,state,pincode,fax) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12)",[name,designation.department,address,phone,mobile,email,organization,city,state,pincode,fax])
 .subscribe(
       data => {
           console.log('success',data)
           /*
           if(data.rowCount > 0){
             httpres.json({status : true ,message : ' ok',parameters:req.body });
           }else{
             httpres.send('error');
           }*/

           if(data.rows[0].exists){
             httpres.json({status : true ,message : 'data inserted',parameters:req.body });
           }else{
            httpres.send('error');
           }


   }, err => {
       console.log('error',err)
       httpres.send('error');
   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put a period (.) instead of a comma (,) between designation and department in the `pool.query`:

```
... [name,designation.department,address,phone,mobile,email,organization,city,state,pincode,fax])
```

Change it to a comma and it should work:

```
... [name,designation,department,address,phone,mobile,email,organization,city,state,pincode,fax])
```

Comment: Got it bro Thanks!

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the tip. I'll try to improve my voting from now.

Comment: I appreciate the quick and kind comeback!